# How to change Column Header Font size , Color, Background color in Syncfusion EJ2 Tree-grid on click event?

Tags: colors, fonts, background-color, contextmanager, treegrid

How to change Column Header Font size , Color, Background color in Syncfusion EJ2 Tree-grid on click event ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <button (click)="Onclick()"></button>
    <ejs-treegrid>
    <e-column field='Name' [customAttributes]="{class: 'playernamecss'}"> 
    </e-column>
    <ejs-treegrid>
```

Typescript / JS:

```
    var r:document.querySelector(':root');
    Onclick(){
    this.r.style.setProperty('--NameBGcolor','black');         
      }
```

CSS:

```
    :root{
           --NameBGcolor:white;
         }
    .e-treegrid .playernamecss{
            background-color : var(--NameBGcolor);
                          }
```

*Same Applies for font-color;Size;width..ect...It worked for me, Hope it works for you too, thanks:)